# Using Oracle combine three tables to one with PIVOT

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three Oracle SQL select queries which returns following results. 
First select query returns result:

```
 user_id | user_name |
---------|-----------|
     1   |   user_1  |
     2   |   user_2  |
     3   |   user_3  |
     4   |   user_4  |
```

second select query returns result:

```
 exam_id | exam_name |
---------|-----------|
    1    |   exam_1  |
    2    |   exam_2  |
    3    |   exam_3  |
```

and the third select query returns result:

```
 exam_id | user_id | exam_date |
---------|---------|-----------|
    1    |    1    |    2017   |
    1    |    2    |    2018   |
    1    |    3    |    2017   |
    2    |    3    |    2018   |
```

I would like to combine these queries to get result:

```
 user_id | user_name | exam_1 | exam_2 | exam_3 |
---------|-----------|--------|--------|--------|
     1   |   user_1  |  2017  |        |        |
     2   |   user_2  |  2018  |        |        |
     3   |   user_3  |  2017  |  2018  |        |
     4   |   user_4  |        |        |        |
```

I would be grateful for any help?

---

Thank you @shrek for helping me out here. I managed to create the variable for pivot values but couldn't put the variable in the pivot. So I got help for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51207675/using-oracle-can-i-use-dynamically-created-variable-in-the-pivot-clause) and the final version (for 11g) looks like this:

```
variable x REFCURSOR
DECLARE
    exam_ids   VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
    SELECT
        LISTAGG(''''
                  || exam_id
                  || ''' AS "'
                  || exam_name
                  || '"',',') WITHIN GROUP(
            ORDER BY
                exam_id ASC
        )
    INTO exam_ids
    FROM
        exam;

    OPEN :x FOR 'SELECT
        *
               FROM
        (
            SELECT
                u.user_id,
                u.user_name,
                e.exam_id,
                eu.exam_date
            FROM
                users u
                LEFT JOIN exam_user eu ON u.user_id = eu.user_id
                LEFT JOIN exam e ON e.exam_id = eu.exam_id
            ORDER BY
                u.user_id
        )
            PIVOT ( MAX ( exam_date )
                FOR exam_id
                IN ( ' || EXAM_IDS || ' )
            )
    ORDER BY
        1';
END;
/

print x
```

---

So that works in the SQL Developer and SQL*Plus. But not when trying to use database with PHP file. For that I needed to create procedure which then could be called from PHP file. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304312/using-oracle-and-php-works-in-sql-developer-but-php-file-results-ora-00900-inv) is problem when trying to use code above from PHP file and the resolution.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to put those 3 results to the single table from which I think I could probably pull out that last pivot table, but I didn't manage that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you going -

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (user_id varchar2(9), user_name varchar2(11))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO users (user_id, user_name)
         VALUES ('1', 'user_1')
    INTO users (user_id, user_name)
         VALUES ('2', 'user_2')
    INTO users (user_id, user_name)
         VALUES ('3', 'user_3')
    INTO users (user_id, user_name)
         VALUES ('4', 'user_4')
SELECT * FROM dual
;

CREATE TABLE exam
    (exam_id varchar2(9), exam_name varchar2(11))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO exam (exam_id, exam_name)
         VALUES ('1', 'exam_1')
    INTO exam (exam_id, exam_name)
         VALUES ('2', 'exam_2')
    INTO exam (exam_id, exam_name)
         VALUES ('3', 'exam_3')
SELECT * FROM dual
;

CREATE TABLE exam_user
    (exam_id varchar2(9), user_id varchar2(9), exam_date varchar2(11))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO exam_user (exam_id, user_id, exam_date)
         VALUES ('1', '1', '2017')
    INTO exam_user (exam_id, user_id, exam_date)
         VALUES ('1', '2', '2018')
    INTO exam_user (exam_id, user_id, exam_date)
         VALUES ('1', '3', '2017')
    INTO exam_user (exam_id, user_id, exam_date)
         VALUES ('2', '3', '2018')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

Query -

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT U.USER_ID, U.USER_NAME, E.EXAM_NAME,EU.EXAM_DATE
FROM USERS U, EXAM E, EXAM_USER EU
WHERE U.USER_ID = EU.USER_ID(+)
AND E.EXAM_ID(+) = EU.EXAM_ID
ORDER BY U.USER_ID
  )
  PIVOT (MAX(EXAM_DATE) FOR EXAM_NAME IN ('exam_1' as exam_1, 'exam_2' as exam_2,'exam_3' as exam_3))
  order by 1
;
```

> Output -

```
USER_ID USER_NAME   EXAM_1  EXAM_2  EXAM_3
1   user_1  2017    (null)  (null)
2   user_2  2018    (null)  (null)
3   user_3  2017    2018    (null)
4   user_4  (null)  (null)  (null)
```

Comment: A nice answer . . . until it comes to the commas used for joins.  You should learn to use explicit, proper, standard `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i'll try doing it going forward.