# Joining three tables which include where clauses each

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have following code:

```
SELECT KAYTTAJA.ti_ka_kayttajaid as USER_ID, 
       KAYTTAJA.ti_ka_etunimi as USER_NAME, 
       EXAM.ti_su_sitoumusid as SITOUMUS_ID, 
       EXAM.ti_su_nimitys as SITOUMUS_NAME, 
       PVM.ti_sk_paivamaara AS SITOUMUS_DATE
FROM ti_sitoumus_kayttaja PVM
    WHERE PVM.ti_sk_kayttajaid IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ti_kayttajantyoyksikko.ti_kt_kayttajaid
        FROM ti_kayttajantyoyksikko 
        WHERE ti_kayttajantyoyksikko.ti_kt_tyoyksikko IN(
            SELECT DISTINCT ti_esimiehentyoyksikko.ti_et_tyoyksikkoid
            FROM ti_esimiehentyoyksikko 
            WHERE ti_esimiehentyoyksikko.ti_et_kayttajaid=14784)) 
JOIN ti_kayttaja KAYTTAJA
    WHERE KAYTTAJA.ti_ka_kayttajaid IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ti_kayttajantyoyksikko.ti_kt_kayttajaid
        FROM ti_kayttajantyoyksikko 
        WHERE ti_kayttajantyoyksikko.ti_kt_tyoyksikko IN(
            SELECT DISTINCT ti_esimiehentyoyksikko.ti_et_tyoyksikkoid
            FROM ti_esimiehentyoyksikko 
            WHERE ti_esimiehentyoyksikko.ti_et_kayttajaid=14784))
ON PVM.ti_sk_kayttajaid(+) = KAYTTAJA.ti_ka_kayttajaid
JOIN FROM ti_sitoumus EXAM
    WHERE EXAM.ti_su_sitoumusid IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ti_kayttooikeus_ryhma.ti_kr_kayttokohdeid
        FROM ti_kayttooikeus_ryhma 
        WHERE ti_kayttooikeus_ryhma.ti_kr_kayttokohde = 6 
        AND ti_kayttooikeus_ryhma.ti_kr_kohdeid IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT ti_esimiehentyoyksikko.ti_et_tyoyksikkoid
            FROM ti_esimiehentyoyksikko 
            WHERE ti_esimiehentyoyksikko.ti_et_kayttajaid=14784))
ON PVM.ti_sk_sitoumusid = EXAM.ti_su_sitoumusid(+)
ORDER BY KAYTTAJA.ti_ka_kayttajaid;
```

This gives me an error: "SQL command not properly ended." At least first JOIN does not work and I don't know how to fix it. Ultimately I'm trying to achieve this: [Using Oracle combine three tables to one with PIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50362410/using-oracle-combine-three-tables-to-one-with-pivot) but I should use some kind of a JOIN syntax when I connect the tables.

Comment: You have many issues in this query. Try to start with a single JOIN and then add the other tables, keeping in mind the structure `SELECT... FROM ... JOIN ... ON ... JOIN ... ON ... WHERE ... ` Also, you are mixing the ANSI syntax with the Oracle old (+) operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your have three options to join tables with WHERE clauses:

1 Join the tables and put all the where clauses at the end (as @Amir Pashazadeh has answered.

```
SELECT *
 FROM table1 JOIN table2 
WHERE conditions_on_table1
  AND conditions_on_table2 ...
```

2 Join subqueries including where conditions

```
SELECT *
 FROM table1
 JOIN (SELECT columns_I_need
        FROM table2
       WHERE conditions_on_table2)
   ON table1.col = table2.col
```

3 Use the WITH clause to chop the query into bits that are easier to understand (and test).

I would normally use option 3 for such a query. You seem to use the tables ti_kayttajantyoyksikko and ti_esimiehentyoyksikko twice, so I'd stick them in a subquery:

```
WITH 
  my_unit AS (
    SELECT t1.ti_kt_kayttajaid AS USER_ID
      FROM ti_kayttajantyoyksikko t1
      JOIN ti_esimiehentyoyksikko t2
        ON t1.ti_kt_tyoyksikko = t2.ti_et_tyoyksikkoid
      WHERE t2.ti_et_kayttajaid = 14794)
SELECT * FROM my_unit;
```

Once that does what I expect, I'd add the next part:

```
WITH 
  my_unit AS (
    SELECT t1.ti_kt_kayttajaid AS USER_ID
      FROM ti_kayttajantyoyksikko t1
      JOIN ti_esimiehentyoyksikko t2
        ON t1.ti_kt_tyoyksikko = t2.ti_et_tyoyksikkoid
      WHERE t2.ti_et_kayttajaid = 14794),
  my_users AS (
    SELECT k.ti_ka_kayttajaid as USER_ID
           k.ti_ka_etunimi    as USER_NAME
      FROM ti_kayttaja k
      JOIN my_unit u ON k.ti_ka_kayttajaid = u.user_id)
SELECT * FROM my_users;
```

... then ...

```
WITH 
  my_unit AS (
    SELECT t1.ti_kt_kayttajaid AS USER_ID
      FROM ti_kayttajantyoyksikko t1
      JOIN ti_esimiehentyoyksikko t2
        ON t1.ti_kt_tyoyksikko = t2.ti_et_tyoyksikkoid
      WHERE t2.ti_et_kayttajaid = 14794),
  my_users AS (
    SELECT k.ti_ka_kayttajaid as USER_ID
           k.ti_ka_etunimi    as USER_NAME
      FROM ti_kayttaja k
      JOIN my_unit u ON k.ti_ka_kayttajaid = u.user_id)
  my_pvm AS (
    SELECT PVM.PVM.ti_sk_kayttajaid AS USER_ID
           PVM.ti_sk_paivamaara     AS SITOUMUS_DATE
      FROM ti_sitoumus_kayttaja PVM
      JOIN my_unit u ON k.ti_kt_tyoyksikko = u.user_id)
SELECT * 
  FROM      my_users 
  LEFT JOIN my_pvm USING (user_id);
```

... and finally ...

```
WITH 
  my_unit AS (
    SELECT t1.ti_kt_kayttajaid AS USER_ID
      FROM ti_kayttajantyoyksikko t1
      JOIN ti_esimiehentyoyksikko t2
        ON t1.ti_kt_tyoyksikko = t2.ti_et_tyoyksikkoid
      WHERE t2.ti_et_kayttajaid = 14794),
  my_users AS (
    SELECT k.ti_ka_kayttajaid as USER_ID
           k.ti_ka_etunimi    as USER_NAME
      FROM ti_kayttaja k
      JOIN my_unit u ON k.ti_ka_kayttajaid = u.user_id)
  my_pvm AS (
    SELECT PVM.PVM.ti_sk_kayttajaid AS USER_ID
           PVM.ti_sk_paivamaara     AS SITOUMUS_DATE,
           PVM.ti_sk_sitoumusid     AS SITOUMUS_ID
      FROM ti_sitoumus_kayttaja PVM
      JOIN my_unit u ON k.ti_kt_tyoyksikko = u.user_id),
  my_exam AS (
    SELECT EXAM.ti_su_sitoumusid as SITOUMUS_ID, 
           EXAM.ti_su_nimitys    as SITOUMUS_NAME
      FROM ti_sitoumus EXAM
     WHERE EXISTS (
             SELECT *
               FROM ti_kayttooikeus_ryhma t3
               JOIN ti_esimiehentyoyksikko t4
                 ON t3.ti_kr_kohdeid = t4.ti_et_tyoyksikkoid
              WHERE t3.ti_kr_kayttokohde = 6
                AND t4.ti_et_kayttajaid = 14784
                AND EXAM.ti_su_sitoumusid = t3.ti_kr_kayttokohdeid))
SELECT user_id, user_name, sitoumus_id, sitoumus_name, sitoumus_date
  FROM my_users 
  LEFT JOIN my_pvm  USING (user_id)
  LEFT JOIN my_exam USING (sitoumus_id)
 ORDER BY user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Move all the `where` clauses to the end of query, so it will be something like

```
SELECT KAYTTAJA.ti_ka_kayttajaid as USER_ID, KAYTTAJA.ti_ka_etunimi as USER_NAME, EXAM.ti_su_sitoumusid as SITOUMUS_ID, EXAM.ti_su_nimitys as SITOUMUS_NAME, PVM.ti_sk_paivamaara AS SITOUMUS_DATE
FROM ti_sitoumus_kayttaja PVM
left JOIN ti_kayttaja KAYTTAJA ON PVM.ti_sk_kayttajaid = KAYTTAJA.ti_ka_kayttajaid
left JOIN FROM ti_sitoumus EXAM ON PVM.ti_sk_sitoumusid = EXAM.ti_su_sitoumusid

WHERE PVM.ti_sk_kayttajaid IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ti_kayttajantyoyksikko.ti_kt_kayttajaid
    FROM ti_kayttajantyoyksikko 
    WHERE ti_kayttajantyoyksikko.ti_kt_tyoyksikko IN(
        SELECT DISTINCT ti_esimiehentyoyksikko.ti_et_tyoyksikkoid
        FROM ti_esimiehentyoyksikko 
        WHERE ti_esimiehentyoyksikko.ti_et_kayttajaid=14784)) 

and KAYTTAJA.ti_ka_kayttajaid IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ti_kayttajantyoyksikko.ti_kt_kayttajaid
    FROM ti_kayttajantyoyksikko 
    WHERE ti_kayttajantyoyksikko.ti_kt_tyoyksikko IN(
        SELECT DISTINCT ti_esimiehentyoyksikko.ti_et_tyoyksikkoid
        FROM ti_esimiehentyoyksikko 
        WHERE ti_esimiehentyoyksikko.ti_et_kayttajaid=14784))


and EXAM.ti_su_sitoumusid IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ti_kayttooikeus_ryhma.ti_kr_kayttokohdeid
    FROM ti_kayttooikeus_ryhma 
    WHERE ti_kayttooikeus_ryhma.ti_kr_kayttokohde = 6 
    AND ti_kayttooikeus_ryhma.ti_kr_kohdeid IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ti_esimiehentyoyksikko.ti_et_tyoyksikkoid
        FROM ti_esimiehentyoyksikko 
        WHERE ti_esimiehentyoyksikko.ti_et_kayttajaid=14784))

ORDER BY KAYTTAJA.ti_ka_kayttajaid;
```

By the way you can not use `(+)` with `ANSI JOINS`, if you want to use `ANSI JOINS` use `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` instead of `(+)`.

Answer (score 0):

Many issues in your query. You need to:

```
SELECT
FROM table1, table2, table3   -- since you're using (+)
WHERE table2.joinKeyTable1 (+) = table1.joinKeyTable2
AND   table3.joinKeyTable1 (+) = table1.joinKeyTable3
AND <all filters>
```

Note: Since it is an outer join - as you seem to require, you need to have (+) next to any column of table2, and table3 in all filters: Example:

```
AND table2.columnX (+) IN (...)
```

or

```
AND table3.columnY (+) = ...
```

This will retrieve all records of table1 that do not have corresponding (childs) in table2, or table3 regardless of the filters you have on corresponding table2/table3 columns

Comment: It would be better to change the (default inner) joins to `OUTER JOIN` and lose the old-style `(+)`, rather than reverting to old-style joins based on a list of tables in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood everything correctly here, but it appears that the driving table for the query is `TI_KAYTTAJA` with the other two principal tables (`TI_SITOUMUS_KAYTTAJA` and `TI_SITOUMUS`) providing optional data. If this is correct then the following query should give you what you're looking for:

```
WITH cteTYOYKSIKKO AS
  (SELECT DISTINCT te.TI_ET_TYOYKSIKKOID
     FROM TI_ESIMIEHENTYOYKSIKKO te
     WHERE te.TI_ET_KAYTTAJAID = 14784)
SELECT k.TI_KA_KAYTTAJAID AS USER_ID, 
       k.TI_KA_ETUNIMI AS USER_NAME, 
       exam.TI_SU_SITOUMUSID AS SITOUMUS_ID, 
       exam.TI_SU_NIMITYS AS SITOUMUS_NAME, 
       pvm.TI_SK_PAIVAMAARA AS SITOUMUS_DATE
  FROM TI_KAYTTAJA k
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TI_SITOUMUS_KAYTTAJA pvm
    ON pvm.TI_SK_KAYTTAJAID = k.TI_KA_KAYTTAJAID AND
       pvm.TI_SK_KAYTTAJAID IN (SELECT DISTINCT tkt.TI_KT_KAYTTAJAID
                                  FROM TI_KAYTTAJANTYOYKSIKKO tkt
                                  INNER JOIN cteTYOYKSIKKO c
                                    ON c.TI_ET_TYOYKSIKKOID = tkt.TI_KT_TYOYKSIKKO
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TI_SITOUMUS exam
    ON exam.TI_SU_SITOUMUSID = pvm.TI_SK_SITOUMUSID AND
       exam.TI_SU_SITOUMUSID IN (SELECT DISTINCT tkr.TI_KR_KAYTTOKOHDEID
                                   FROM TI_KAYTTOOIKEUS_RYHMA tkr
                                   INNER JOIN cteTYOYKSIKKO c
                                     ON c.TI_ET_TYOYKSIKKOID = tkr.TI_KR_KOHDEID
                                   WHERE tkr.TI_KR_KAYTTOKOHDE = 6)
  WHERE k.TI_KA_KAYTTAJAID IN (SELECT DISTINCT tk.TI_KT_KAYTTAJAID
                                 FROM TI_KAYTTAJANTYOYKSIKKO tk
                                 INNER JOIN cteTYOYKSIKKO c
                                   ON c.TI_ET_TYOYKSIKKOID = tk.TI_KT_TYOYKSIKKO)
  ORDER BY k.TI_KA_KAYTTAJAID
```

The above assumes that the data retrieved from `TI_SITOUMUS_KAYTTAJA` and `TI_SITOUMUS` are optional in the query, based on the presence of `(+)` qualifiers in the original query. If this is incorrect for one or both of these tables the join type should be changed from `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

Best of luck.