# Using Oracle and PHP: Works in SQL Developer but PHP file results ORA-00900: Invalid Statement

Tags: php, oracle

When I take the code from my earlier post "[Using Oracle combine three tables to one with PIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50362410/using-oracle-combine-three-tables-to-one-with-pivot)" and hit "Run Script" in SQL Developer everything works just perfectly but when I try to execute same script from PHP file I get "ORA-00900 Invalid SQL Statement" -error. SQL Developers "Run Statement" fails as well to execute the code. It seems my code isn't in the "SQL Statement" syntax?

My PHP code for putting sql script in the variable:

```
$sql = "variable x REFCURSOR
DECLARE
    exam_ids   VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
    SELECT
        LISTAGG(''''
                  || exam_id
                  || ''' AS \"'
                  || exam_name
                  || '\"',',') WITHIN GROUP(
            ORDER BY
                exam_id ASC
        )
    INTO exam_ids
    FROM
        exam;

    OPEN :x FOR 'SELECT
        *
               FROM
        (
            SELECT
                u.user_id,
                u.user_name,
                e.exam_id,
                eu.exam_date
            FROM
                users u
                LEFT JOIN exam_user eu ON u.user_id = eu.user_id
                LEFT JOIN exam e ON e.exam_id = eu.exam_id
            ORDER BY
                u.user_id
        )
            PIVOT ( MAX ( exam_date )
                FOR exam_id
                IN ( ' || EXAM_IDS || ' )
            )
    ORDER BY
        1';
END;
/

print x";
```

Then I pass the $sql variable to function for the results:

```
function getSQLResult($sql, $conn) {
    $stmt = OCIParse($conn, $sql);

    if( $stmt === false ) {
        errorShutdown(__('...'), __('...'));
        die();
    } else {
        //Executes a statement
        if (OCIExecute($stmt)) {
            return $stmt;
        }
        else {
          $err = oci_error($stmt);
          echo '<pre>';
          print_r($err);
          echo '</pre>';
          return false;
        }
    }
}
```

So can anyone show me how to refactor the code?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If it's Oracle, why did you tag SQL Server? I've removed the irrelevant tag for you. Please don't tag an RDBMS you're not using when asking a question, it only confuses the volunteers that re trying to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured that out. It seems that needed to make from that PL/SQL script a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getExamStatus(RC OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
    exam_ids   VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
    SELECT
        LISTAGG(''''
                  || exam_id
                  || ''' AS \"'
                  || exam_name
                  || '\"',',') WITHIN GROUP(
            ORDER BY
                exam_id ASC
        )
    INTO exam_ids
    FROM
        exam;

    OPEN rc FOR 'SELECT
        *
               FROM
        (
            SELECT
                u.user_id,
                u.user_name,
                e.exam_id,
                eu.exam_date
            FROM
                users u
                LEFT JOIN exam_user eu ON u.user_id = eu.user_id
                LEFT JOIN exam e ON e.exam_id = eu.exam_id
            ORDER BY
                u.user_id
        )
            PIVOT ( MAX ( exam_date )
                FOR exam_id
                IN ( ' || EXAM_IDS || ' )
            )
    ORDER BY
        1';
END;
/
```

Then run that procedure in the database. After that in the PHP file I had to refactor the sql statement:

```
$sql = "BEGIN getExamStatus(:rc); END;";
```

And the function:

```
function getSQLResult($sql, $conn) {
    $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

    if( $stmt === false ) {
        errorShutdown(__('...'), __('...'));
        die();
    } else {
        $rc = oci_new_cursor($conn);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':rc', $rc, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);
        if(!oci_execute($stmt)) {
            return false;
            //return oci_error($stmt);
        }
        if(!oci_execute($rc)) {
            return false;
            //return oci_error($stmt);
        }
        $results = array();
        while (($row = oci_fetch_array($rc, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
            $results[] = $row;
        }
        oci_free_statement($stmt);
        oci_free_statement($rc);
        return $results;
    }
}
```